# Erdös-Renyi Model with prescribed subgraph

Tags: co.combinatorics, pr.probability, random-graphs

In  the  Erdös-Rényi  model for  random  graphs  there  is  a  lot  of  results stating   sharp phase  transitions  for the   probability  of  a random graph  to  contain  a  fixed  prescribed  subgraph.

Is  there  a  model  of Erdös-Renyi graphs, which  do  contain  a  fixed  subgraph?

Comment: This is probably not exactly what you are interested in, but there is an interesting theory of conditioning an ER random graph on containing many more than its expected number of some prescribed subgraph, e.g., triangles: https://yufeizhao.wordpress.com/2014/02/25/upper-tail/

Comment: Could you possibly say a little more about what you're after?  For me the key feature of the Erdős–Rényi model is the independence of edges, which doesn't play nicely with most additional conditions.